# Compare date time in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contain datetime

```
 array(3) {
  [1368090995]=>
  object(stdClass)#375 (1) {
   ["submitted"]=>
   string(10) "1368090995"
 }
  [1368091032]=>
  object(stdClass)#376 (1) {
   ["submitted"]=>
  string(10) "1368091032"
 }
  [1368091070]=>
  object(stdClass)#372 (1) {
   ["submitted"]=>
  string(10) "1368091070"
 }
}
```

I want to get the latest time from this array.

How can I compare the datatime from array?

Comment: Make sure it's an array and use `max()`?

Answer (score 5):

As you have the timestamps as keys you could quite simply do this

```
$timestamps = array_keys($your_array);
$latest = max($timestamps);
```

`array_keys()` returns an array of all the keys in your input array
`max()` accepts an array of numbers and returns the highest number and therefore in this instance the latest time

Comment: I dont need to change it back to datetime before compare?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your example array of obejcts, you could use

```
$latest = max(array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort($array);
print_r(array_shift($array));
```